# Can I convert Babel generated code back to ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Can I convert Babel generated code back to ES6. I have some code converted generated by babel run time but having a hardtime to understand the code

Comment: I don't know of any tools. It's easier to remove features than automatically add features

Comment: Is this your own source code that you accidentally converted all to pre-ES6 and deleted the original?

Comment: Babel translates JavaScript ES6 to JavaScript ES5. chromes Pretty print can make it slightly more readable but you would need a tool like lebab js (babel in reverse) to convert es5 to es6. If you have the original source code. it is better to avoid minifiying the code in the first place

Comment: @Samathingamajig it's a third party library. So, sadly i don't have the corresponding ES6.

Comment: @JDavies yes I tried using lebab js but it has some limitations. I think I have to convert it chunk-by-chunk by myself.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the source code of the library? If they're distributing the transpiled (ES5) version for free on npm or similar, they probably have the source code released as well.